# How to notify a Fragment in the Backstack that it is on top again

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

Since Fragments were introduced I keep my eyes open for a good solution to update a Fragment to which I'm going back to.

**This is my scenario:**

I have a One-Activity App. When the App starts it shows a FirstFragment. With a button click the user can open a SecondFragment. Both Fragments are full screen and will be opened via androids NavController.

Note: Both fragments get their data from a rx-based repository. The repository and its underlying classes handle all CRUD operations.

**What I want to do:**

Updating the FirstFragment as soon as the user clicks back on the SecondFragment OR in other words: I want to update the FirstFragment as soon as it comes on top from the background.

**The Problem**

The FirstFragment gets no callback or livecycle event if it comes into view again.

In the past I solved this problem with a ListenerInterface that was triggered in the activities onBackPressed or with a broadcast event. But is there no better solution? I question if there is a possibility via LiveData or via NavController or anything else. Or does anybody know how google solves this problem?

**What I NOT want to do**

As my data layer is based on rx I could of course have a BehaviourSubject that I subscribe on in the FirstFragment. Then when I switch to SecondFragment I could keep the subscription undisposed so the FirstFragment will be updated as soon as i call onNext on the BehaviourSubject. I've seen apps doing this and it seems wrong to me. In my opinion a subscription should be disposed as soon as another ViewModel steps into place.

Thanks in advance

[Android, notify backstack fragments on some change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50059290/android-notify-backstack-fragments-on-some-change)

Comment: How about sharing the viewmodel between the fragments if there is enough common logic involved?

Comment: I agree with @sonnet. sharing viewmodel and observing livedata would fit your case.

Comment: other way to update the fragment when it appears is use override method setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser), it returns boolean when fragment visibility changes.

Comment: @Raza `setUserVisibleHint` is deprecated.

Comment: @Emanuel `FirstFragment` should be getting `onStart` event. Using `LiveData` should automatically trigger a resubscription in `onStart`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce The FirstFragment does not get any lifecycle event at all. If it would get an onStart event it would be sufficient for me.

Comment: @sonnet to share the viewmodel is an interesting idea but not suitable for me. I have a huge app and the navigation is not as straight as i.e. settings. I can navigate to a screen from different fragments and need this update mechanism nearly everywhere. That would mean I have a lot of viewmodels to share which would make my viewmodel class too heavy.

Comment: Then the only option I see is, extract that shared code in a separate class (usecase/interactor/whatever), expose an rx observable, make it scoped (application /activity/logged-in-user/singleton scope), then inject it into the viewmodels through dagger.

Comment: There is an OnDestinationChangedListener that could be worth checking out. I will update my post as soon as I found time to investigate this option. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui

Comment: The OnBackPressedCallback could be a help. I will check this out https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back

Comment: Here is another thread about a similar topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326155/fragment-onresume-onpause-is-not-called-on-backstack